# PHP Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context

Tags: php, php-5.3

```
if (isset( $xml->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="extralarge"]')[0])) {
```

PHP Version 5.3 in use (was 5.7 until server dude switched it to 5.3).

On the line at the top we're getting this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Can't use method return value in write context
```

I've read a few articles but nothing obvious springs to mind - might be a case of not seeing the wood through the trees.

Any advice on how to get rid of the error other than switching back to 5.7?

Comment: Array dereferencing introduced in `php5.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For compatibility with PHP < 5.4, update your code as follows:

```
$elements = $xml->xpath('/lfm/artist/image[@size="extralarge"]');
if (isset($elements[0])) {
```

Take a look at https://wiki.php.net/rfc/functionarraydereferencing if you're interested in learning more.